# Firebase rules not allowing to read from database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The issue I have is that with the following firebase rules shown below an authenticated user can successfully write to a database but cannot read from it as I get a "permission denied" in the console. When I set both read and write to true (public) then both read and write function are both working correctly. My code for reading from the database is also shown below:

```
 private String userID;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //Authenticate user
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
        userID = user.getUid();

public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ArrayList<CharSequence> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(HomeActivity.this.getResources().getTextArray(R.array.array)));
                        map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.child("users").child(userID).getValue();
                        int x = 16;
                        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                            String key = entry.getKey();
                            array.add(x, key);
                            x++;
                        }
```

rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

example database:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "9kV3otdvOXU0ssMZWIdfggrBrj63" : {
      "Citrus" : [ "orange", "lime", "mandarin", "lemon" ],
      "Fruit" : [ "apple", "banana", "mango" ],
      "Meat" : [ "beef", "pork", "lamb", "chicken" ],
      "Veg" : [ "tomato", "potato", "cabbage" ]
    }
  }
}
```

here is the exact error:

```
W/SyncTree: Listen at / failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please show more than just the one line of code.  What you're showing isn't really a query.  It's just accessing data inside snapshot that came from a prior query.

Comment: I edited the code there

Comment: You're still not showing the query itself.  You're showing the listener from a query.

Comment: that is the query, I am requesting to read from the database

Comment: looks fine to me, try maybe switching === to ==; I always put this comparison operator in the rules

Comment: Nope still the same problem, It writes just fine but does not want to read for some reason

Comment: This is the error: `W/SyncTree: Listen at / failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

As Doug already commented, it's hard to help without seeing what data you attach the listener to (so the `DatabaseReference` on which you call `addValueListener` or `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`). But from this code in your listener it seems that you're listening for `/`.

```
dataSnapshot.child("users")
```

None of your users have permission to read `/`, since you only give them access to `/users/$uid`. Not only is your code now violating your security rules, if it worked it would download way more data than is needed.

Instead you should attach your listener to the lowest level in the JSON tree that contains all the data that you need (and have read permission to). In your case that seems to be `/users/$uid`, so you'd do:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
DatabaseReference userRef = usersRef.child(userID);
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    ArrayList<CharSequence> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(HomeActivity.this.getResources().getTextArray(R.array.array)));
        map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        int x = 16;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            array.add(x, key);
            x++;
        }
```

Comment: The data is attached to an ArrayList as shown in the code. How could I fix it?

Comment: The code both Doug and I have been asking for is your equivalent of the first three lines in the snippet I shared. Without that it's hard to know what data your `ValueEventListener` is trying to read. The error message in this case helped, but the best way to ask for help is to create a [minimal complete, standalone reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I posted it there, Im still getting the same error though

Comment: Getting a new error now sorry `java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()`

Comment: That's a different problem. The error says that you're passing `null` into a call to `child`. Most likely that means that `userID` has no value.